# Call TemplateField DropDownList in asp.net - code behind with FindControl()

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, findcontrol

This is how i created my `DropDownListLehrbeginn` in my GridView. sss

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lehrbeginn" SortExpression="lehrbeginn" HeaderStyle-Width="40px"> 
       <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListLehrbeginn" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelLehrbeginn" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lehrbeginn") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to add ListItems with c# like this:

```
DropDownListLehrbeginn.Items.Add(new ListItem(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()));
DropDownListLehrbeginn.Items.Add(new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year.ToString()));
DropDownListLehrbeginn.Items.Add(new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddYears(2).Year.ToString()));
DropDownListLehrbeginn.Items[1].Selected = true;
```

It doesnt work unfortunately. How can i fix this issue? `DropDownListLehrbeginn` is not available in code behind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net find control in gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356552/asp-net-find-control-in-gridview)

Comment: it doesnt work like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Because your drop down list is within another element you probably just need to use something like this

```
DropDownList ddlList = (DropDownList)NameOfGridView.FindControl("DropDownListLehrbeginn");
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me. the dropdownlist remains empty